# Економний чи економічний

Tags: значення-слів, правопис

Чи є нормальним варіант вживання слова **економічний** в сенсі *ощадливий*?
У різних словниках це значення вживається в різних варіантах: як *економний*, так і *економічний*.

> <sub>**[Словник-довідник з українського літературного слововживання / С. І. Головащук](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001523)** : [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53397/30739.html), [Словник.мі](https://slovnyk.me/dict/linguistic_norm/%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), [Студопедия.ру](https://studopedia.ru/16_67065_ekonomichniy--ekonomniy.html)</sub>
>
> **Економічний**
>
> 1. Який стосується сукупності суспільно-виробничих відносин, господарського життя тощо: *економічна боротьба, економічна криза, економічне життя, економічний журнал, економічна географія*.
> 2. Вигідний у господарському відношенні: *економічний проект, економічний режим, економічний холодильник, економічна технологія*.
>
> **Економний**
>
> Який ощадливо витрачає щось, сприяє економії тощо: *економне витрачання коштів, економні рухи, економний опис, бути економним*. Пох.: **економність**, **економно**.

**В російській мові** є чітка градація цих понять:

- *экономный* — по відношенню до людини;
- *экономичный* — по відношенню до сфери, процесу, способу або режиму;
- *экономический* — по відношенню до економіки.

**В українській мові**:

- *економний* може вживатися по відношенню як до людини, так і до режиму використання;
- *економічний* може визначати як поняття, повʼязані з ощадливостю, так і з економікою.

Хочу розібратися в цьому і зрозуміти, чи не є помилкою використовувати слово *економічний* по відношенню до способу або режиму економії.

**Приклади:** сфера економічної/економної витрати палива, сфера економічного/економного друку.

Comment: Зазначу, 1) зміст словника краще виносити сюди, бо тамтешні сторінки, а за ними і тутошні ланки, мають волостивість умирати 2) в трьох ланках був один словник, або радше словник-порадник,

Answer (score 1):

Ні, це неприйнятно. Економічний - це той, що стосується економіки - дисципліни про

> господарство, а саме — виробництво, розподіл і споживання товарів та послуг.

Зрозуміло, що економіка намагається економно/ощадливо використовувати ресурси.

З [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2):

> Суфікси **-ичн-, -ічн- (-їчн-), -арн- (-ярн-)** продуктивні в прикметниках, похідних від іменників іншомовного походження. Вони виражають відношення до певної галузі науки, громадсько-політичного напряму тощо: історичний, гуманітарний, молекулярний.

І звідти ж:

> Ціла низка суфіксів формує якісні та відносно-якісні прикметники, мотивовані іменниковими або дієслівними основами: ...; **-н-** (сильний, активний, надійний, вичерпний, поважний, розумний, сонний); ...

Отже, якщо у людини є (її властиві) *сила, надія, економія*, то ця людина *сильна, надійна, економна.*

Comment: Дякую за роз’яснення, Yola. Але питань стосовно людини як раз немає. Людина — без сумніву «економна». Питання стосується сфери. Наприклад, сфера економного (чи економічного) друку.

Answer (score 1):

Чисто суб'єктивно я згоден з [Yola](/a/6351) — навіщо змішувати в одному прикметнику *економічний* значення «такий, що стосується економіки» і «такий, що стосується економії», хай *економний* буде «той, що стосується економії», а *економічний* — «той, що стосується економіки».

Але якщо глянути об'єктивніше, то серйозні словники дають слову *економічний* і значення «(який дає можливість зекономити що-небудь) вигідний у господарському відношенні», зокрема:

- Зацитований Вами «Словник-довідник з українського літературного слововживання».
- «Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

  > 3. Який дає можливість зекономити що-небудь; вигідний у господарському відношенні. *Транспортування газу по трубопроводах дуже економічне* (Наука і життя, 12, 1957, 3); *ДТ-54 — більш досконалий, потужний і економічний трактор, ніж ті, що досі вироблялися на заводі* (Іван І. Волошин, Самоцвіти, 1952, 79).
- «Словник української мови» у 20 томах:

  > 3. Який дає можливість зекономити що-небудь; вигідний у господарському відношенні. <s>*Велике значення має постійний контроль основних функціональних параметрів двигуна, від яких залежить не тільки економічна ефективність, а й безпека виконання польотів* (з наук. літ.)</s>; *Транспортування газу трубопроводами дуже економічне* (з наук.-попул. літ.).

  (Першу цитату з СУМ-20 викреслив я, бо вважаю її абсолютно недоречною: у словосполученні *економічна ефективність* прикметник *економічна*, я вважаю, означає саме «стосовний до економіки»; як-от: *математичне очікування*, *статистична значущість* тощо).

Після перечитування наведених Вами і мною прикладів, мені здається, що частині мовців не вистачає розрізнення між «той, що економить» і «той, що дозволяє зекономити комусь». Наприклад, *економне таксі* — для когось це буде не «таксі, що бере малу платню», а «таксі, водій якого береже пальне». Відповідно, частина випадків, коли потрібне значення «той, що дозволяє зекономити комусь», «вилазять» зі слова *економний* на слово *економічний*. Добре це (бо слугує точнішому розрізненню понять) чи навпаки (бо, можливо, наслідок вливу російської) — мені важко сказати.

Comment: Чудово про *економічне* як таке, що дозволяє зекономити.

Comment: Sasha, дуже дякую за те, що відчули неоднозначність вживання слова і пов'язані з цим труднощі вибору.